# Spring Integration: defining inputs for each MessageSource poll

Tags: spring-integration

I've spent a fair amount of time over the past few weeks learning about Spring Integration, and something I'm not seeing in the docs is how the various `MessageSources` prevent themselves (or can be configured to prevent) reading duplicate inputs into the `IntegrationFlows`.

For instance, let's take an FTP server:

```
return IntegrationFlows.from("ftp-endpoint")
    .handle(fileProcessor())
    .get();
```

Let's say at one point in time the directory on the FTP server (indicated by "`ftp-endpoint`" above) has the following files on it:

```
readingDir/
    file1.txt
    file2.txt
    file3.txt
```

The next time the scheduled FTP message source (`ftp-endpoint`) runs, it ingests all 3 files. Then some more files get added:

```
readingDir/
    file1.txt
    file2.txt
    file3.txt
    file4.txt
    file5.txt
```

How do we prevent `file1.txt`, `file2.txt` and `file3.txt` from being read the next time the flow polls the FTP server and runs? What if we actually *want* it to re-run `file3.txt` for some reason -- how would we tell it to read `file3.txt` (re-run), `file4.txt` (new) and `file5.txt` (new) but *skip* `file1.txt` and `file2.txt`?

And this question is not just for FTP, it would be for any polling endpoint: email, DropBox, S3, etc. Hopefully its the same API/strategy for all of them!

The only thing I can see on the API that jumps out is to provide a `SourcePollingChannelAdapterSpec` on the endpoint, so:

```
IntegrationFlows.from("ftp-endpoint", sourcePollingChannelAdapterSpec)...
```

And then configure the `SourcePollingChannelAdapterSpec` to have a piece of `Advice` (`setAdvice(Arrays.asList(specialAdvice))`) that has logic in it, but that feels kind of clumsy (I'm not a huge fan of tag interfaces like `Advice`). I'll use it if that's the only solution, but there's **gotta** be a better way to tell each `MessageSource` what to consider "valid inputs" on each run!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear what resources did you investigate to learn about this stuff.
Please, take a look into official FTP Inbound Channel Adapter docs:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/ftp.html#ftp-inbound

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/file.html#remote-persistent-flf

So, you are fully missing the fact that there is a `FileListFilter` strategy and there are a lot of out-of-the-box implementations for our consideration. What you are asking is covered by the mentioned in the first doc `AcceptOnceFileListFilter`. It does hold a reference to the file to skip it on the next poll. If you'd like to re-fetch some old file, you just can call `AcceptOnceFileListFilter.remove()`. Or look into an `FtpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` which is able to track not just file name, but also its timestamp. So, if the content of remote file is updated, then its timestamp is changed - and this filter would treat the file as new one and will fetch it again.

Comment: Thanks, I _did_ see the `FileListFilter`, but that seems to only be implemented for the FTP adapter. I was hoping there would be an `interface` or API, provided by Spring Integration for filtering inputs like this for _any_ adapter (FTP, S3, email, etc.). Does such an API/mechanism not exist? Is it just left up to the adapter implementation to decide whether to offer or not offer? Thanks again

Comment: Maybe specifying `TransactionSychronizations` for all my inbound adapters? They all seem to support them, and I could apply my own filtering logic inside of the beforeCommit method perhaps?

Comment: I'm not sure what are you talking about. Of course there are some protocol specifics, therefore we suggest a `PersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` impl for those protocols as well. See `SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` and `S3PersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter`. Mail protocol has nothing to do with files. Mail relies on `SEEN` flag set on a read message. For more general solution you may look into an Idempotent Receiver: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#idempotent-receiver